# JavaScript MIME type warning on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, django, firefox

I am loading the java-script file in Django template:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="{% static 'online-v3.js' %}"></script>
```

It is loading properly on Chrome. But, on Firefox I get the following warning:

```
The script from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/myscript.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

I fear that due to this problem, on some browser the JS file might not load at all.

What is the possible reason for this and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I get this warning by HTML using a router (called by .htaccess file) for its loading of a .js file, not using any type attribute in the script element, but only on Firefox, not on Chrome. A bug in Firefox?

Answer (score 7):

Remove the `type` or change it to `"text/javascript"`.

In html5 spec the `type` is not required unless it is *not* javascript

Comment: text/javascript or application/javascript ? I've seen both.

Comment: [mozilla says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#sect4) "Note: Even though any given user agent may support any or all of these, you should only use text/javascript. It's the only MIME type guaranteed to work now and into the future."

Answer (score 4):

To add onto evilpie's answer, the root cause for me was using the basic `py -m http.server` for local testing. In order to correctly assign `.js` files the 'text/javascript' MIME type, I instead use this script from Github user HaiyangXu.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#test on python 3.4 ,python of lower version  has different module organization.
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver

PORT = 8080

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Handler.extensions_map={
        '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
    '.html': 'text/html',
        '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.js':  'application/x-javascript',
    '': 'application/octet-stream', # Default
    }

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/HaiyangXu/ec88cbdce3cdbac7b8d5

Answer (score 2):

Your server is wrongly configured and is serving `.js` files with a wrong `Content-Type` header of `text/plain`.

In the future Firefox might start blocking scripts with incorrect MIME types.

Comment: What's the reason for MIME types? In the case of the common images, js, and css, the meaning of the data is obvious from its HTML context.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this warning for Django debug server on Windows, add following lines in your `settings.py` file

```py
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
```