# Flutter Web: The script from .. was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, go-chi

I have backend code written in golang and fronted using flutter web. I am trying to serve flutter web via chi router and everything seems to work fine but I get the following errors in browser console.

> The script from “http://localhost:8282/flutter.js” was loaded even
> though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME
> type. localhost:8282 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation
> is insecure. Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to
> plain  tag. flutter.js:145:23 The script from
> “http://localhost:8282/main.dart.js” was loaded even though its MIME
> type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
> localhost:8282

My golang server code is as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")

    if port == "" {
        port = "8282"
    }

    router := chi.NewRouter()

    //Status router for testing if server is working
    router.Get("/status", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, _ = w.Write([]byte("It is working!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"))
    })

    //Configuring frontend
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))

    router.Handle("/*", http.StripPrefix("/", fs))

    log.Printf("connect to http://localhost:%s/ for viewing flutter web", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:"+port, router))
}
```

And `index.html` for flutter web

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="futa_web">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>futa_web</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = '532060023';
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have reproduce this issue on github repository [here](https://github.com/kateile/flutter-web-with-golang-server).

Any help to solve this will be appreciated

Comment: on what browser does this happen?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof this is firefox, but it doesnt work in chrome or edge too

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the error message

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure

This might have to do with an insecured connection.
Can you establish a secure connection via `https` instead of `http`?
Possibly related: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1529

2. Regarding the error message

> The script was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432292/javascript-mime-type-warning-on-firefox), your server should not send out `.js` files as `text/plain`. You could either remove the type annotation alltogether or change it to `text/javascript`

Comment: my server sending js as `text/plain` is what I am facing. Any hint how to solve it

Comment: Do you have access to the server in order to change that?

Comment: I have check here https://github.com/kateile/flutter-web-with-golang-server

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by registering mime types everytime server runs by

```golang
func FixMimeTypes() {
    err1 := mime.AddExtensionType(".js", "text/javascript")
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Printf("Error in mime js %s", err1.Error())
    }

    err2 := mime.AddExtensionType(".css", "text/css")
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Printf("Error in mime js %s", err2.Error())
    }
}
```